# Modeling a national dataset at a lower level of census geography

Tags: estimation, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis

I want to build a model from a set of a over 100000 individual survey responses. Then, from the distribution of new responses (not found in the training set) on a subset of questions from the survey, I want to estimate the distribution of responses for the remaining questions.

In particular, the survey that I'm looking at is the consumer expenditure survey (http://www.bls.gov/cex). The response variables include demographic information (race, educational attainment) and consumer spending figures for each of the respondents. Some variables are numerical while other are categorical (USD figure of 1 month's rent, the respondent owns a TiVo yes/no). Some data is missing for various reasons (refused or question is not applicable).

I want to answer questions like:

Given a group among which 50 identified as "White," 75 identified as "Black," 25 as "Asian" etc... and 10 had no schooling, 100 were highschool graduates and 40 had master's degrees:

How many should I expect to own a TiVo? or What should I expect their average rent to be (for those in the group that pay rent)?

Though I understand that I will be making several assumptions in doing so, I would like to use this national survey data to produce estimates for populations of individual counties, census tracts and even "lower" levels of geography by making use of aggregate counts obtained through other sources (it is not difficult to find an estimates of the distribution of racial and educational attainment categories in one county or census tract). By "lower" I mean smaller geographical units.

One example of the sort of thing that I want to produce is this product: http://www.appliedgeographic.com/MethodologyStatements_2014/ConsumerExpenditures2014A.pdf.

What are the names of some of the techniques commonly used to answer questions like the above?

Comment: To what "problem" do you refer?  And by "lower level" do you mean a *smaller* or a *larger* geographic area?

Comment: I edited the question--hopefully it is more clear now and the hold can be removed. By "lower" I mean smaller geographic area.